# VSCode - JUnit Setup Problems

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, installation, junit

I tried to setup up JUnit, but for some reason, vscode does not want me to set up testing for java.
The provided images may help with providing context.

[What the testing tab shows to me in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1f25.png)

[Extension Pack needed for testing Java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVmVW.png)

[Json File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYm8a.png)

I tried to follow https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-testing, but I can't even get past the first step.

Comment: There is a thumb-down icon in the right bottom corner of your VS Code status bar, which means the language support for Java does not start up correctly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ShengChen I suspect that to be the case, I just don't know what's exactly going wrong.

Comment: You can check the logs to see if anything wrong happened. See: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/Troubleshooting#enable-logging

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check Java extension pack is properly installed or not. If there is some issue then restart vscode and then try to reload extension. At last open a java project then try to setup Junit testing environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable `Python` extension and make sure you have installed `Test Runner for Java` extension.